# Rest DSL path typing to a POJO, can I register the POJO as a Bean and call the id to reference it?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel, spring-dsl

This is a very low impact "issue" and I'm just looking out to learn something new about Camel and how it works.

I'm working to build a springboot service using camel context routes, and while it's working fine (so far), I'd like to set the rest path type to a class without having to explicitly call the package location, and instead, reference the class as a bean and use it's id to call it.

I have defined a camelContext, I have the rest, restConfigurations and the necessary http methods (get, post, put...), here's a mock of what I have right now.

I've registered a ServiceImpl class as a bean and have given it the id Service. In the Route, I can call the bean using a ref to it's id, and select the method that I want.

```
<beans xmlns ...>
...
    <!-- start services -->
    <bean class="com.daniel.rest-project.services.ServiceImpl" id="Service"/>
    <!-- end services -->
...
    <camelContext id="context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <rest bindingMode="au            <!-- <to id="to-7b30ace2-b26d-4301-8bb0-ef007d566ab3" uri="direct:501"/>  -->to" enableCORS="true" id="rest">
...
            <post consumes="application/json" id="newTask" produces="application/json" uri="/task" type="com.daniel.rest-project.vo.TaskVO">
                <description>New Task Object</description>
                <param description="Task Object Body." name="body" required="true" type="body"/>
                <to uri="direct:newTask"/>
            </post>
...
        </rest>
...
        <route id="route-task-new">
            <from id="from-task-new" uri="
           <bean id="to-task-new" method="newTask" ref="Service"/>
        </route>
...
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Now, I've actually got implemented around 150 routes (project is pretty big) and I'm tired of having to declare the rest post type, right now it's using something not really similar to com.daniel.rest-project.vo..
There's a ton of classes that are named similarly and due to internal reasons, best practices are scarce, naming conventions are weird, there's more than one package I need to go to, etc.

It would feel a lot more organized to just define all the objects I need at the start of the XML file and reference them as I go, instead of having to state the whole way there every time, so, is there a way I can define those classes at the start, just like the services, and tell the post rest path to use the id of the bean, instead of having to give it the whole class location? There must be a way and I'm sure I've just been blind enough not to see it in the documentation for the past weeks.

Here's one of the methods I've tried thus far:

```
    <!-- start classes -->
    <bean class="com.daniel.rest-project.vo.TaskVO" id="TaskVO"/>
    <!-- end classes -->
```

and then, tell the path to do something like this

```
            <post consumes="application/json" id="newTask" produces="application/json" uri="/task" type="TaskVO">
                <description>New Task Object</description>
                <param description="Task Object Body." name="body" required="true" type="body"/>
                <to uri="direct:newTask"/>
            </post>
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route newTask: Route(newTask)[[From[rest:post:/task?routeId=newTask&... because of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TaskVO
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:209)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1143)
..........
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TaskvO
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1830)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.commit(DefaultRouteContext.java:206)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1307)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:204)
```

TaskVO implements Serializable, and only has one, empty, public constructor, followed by all of it's getters and setters.

Comment: <post consumes="application/json" id="newTask" produces="application/json" uri="/task" type="TaskVO">

I think you are missing the full path for type attribute - com.daniel.rest-project.vo.TaskVO

    <post consumes="application/json" id="newTask" produces="application/json" uri="/task" type="com.daniel.rest-project.vo.TaskVO">

Comment: dear @deo, I'm looking for a way to not have to add the full path for the attribute. The first example I provided has the full path, I'm asking if there's a way to declare the type before, as to not have to add the full path every time. Thanks.